# why isnt this setInveral function working?

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
 function countNum(){
     let num=0;
     function inner(){
            num++
            console.log(num);
               }
          }

 setInterval(countNum,1000)
```

Comment: Add `()` at the end of `countNum` - right now you're periodically executing the OUTER part, not the inner part that does the printing.

Comment: What results you're expect?

Comment: I cant figure out what you are trying to do. The inner function is never called in your code so there will be no output. You are calling the outer function every second.

Comment: either make your inner function self executing or call it explicitly if you are expecting to increment variable num.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining function but not calling

```
function countNum(){
     let num=0;
     function inner(){
            num++
            console.log(num);
               }
              inner();/////////////////////////////
          }

 setInterval(countNum,1000)
```

Comment: nevermind thanks i figured out what else i was doing wrong lol

Comment: `function countNum()
{ 
var num=0; 
function inner()
{ 
num++; 
console.log(num);
 } 
inner(); 
}
 setInterval(countNum,300) ;` is working. may be `let` don't work all the time

Answer (score 1):

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals.

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); 
countNum();
}, 3000);
```

If your requirement is to excute the inner function. return inner function from countNum and proceed like

```
function countNum(){
     let num=0;
     return function (){
            num++
            console.log(num);
               }
          }

 setInterval(function(){  
    var inner = countNum();
    inner();
}, 3000);
```